# TVMLKitErrorDomain error 3 Message

Tags: ios-simulator, apple-tv, tvml

I have a TVML app working quite nicely now in the simulator. I've started with a menuBar template, and have used a stackTemplate as well as productTemplate. Everything is working just dandy in the simulator. However, when I hook my Apple TV up and try to run it on there, the application loads, but then I get the following error:

```
TVMLKitErrorDomain error 3
```

I have been trying to find out what this is for a few days , but I have not found any information pertaining to the error code. The simulator version is running on the localhost 9001 like Apple recommends and that is flawless. I just can't get the app to run properly on the device though. Does anyone know what that error is, and how I can fix it? As always I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7):

You need to run this command from the same directory as your TVMLKit JS file:

`python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9001`
.

Comment: this worked for me using Xcode 9.1 not sure why however thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had same error in my TV app. Solved by editing **Info.plist**. This error indicates that URL user trying to visit is not reachable.

You need to allow **http://** from **Info.plist** for your app.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are running on device, you should change this line from localhost to your IP address:

```
static let TVBaseURL = "http://localhost:9001/"
```

to

```
static let TVBaseURL = "http://MY.IP.ADDRESS.HERE:9001/"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just open a new terminal at your app folder and run the following command before running the simulator:

```
ruby -run -ehttpd . -p9001
```